# Possible to Run Goal Seek on array elements within VBA, instead of an Excel sheet range?

Tags: arrays, vba

**Possible to Run Goal Seek on array elements within VBA, instead of an Excel sheet range?**

I have an array that takes initial values from an excel input sheet, does many calculations, and prints values back into a report region on an excel sheet; the output is roughly 200 rows x 28 columns of calculated values. I used to do this with formulas in every cell, but it was very, very slow. I converted to an all-vba Sub that does the calculations quickly and pastes the finished values into the report range in excel.

The problem is that I also need to run Goal Seek on various cells and Excel can't do it on a cell that just has a value, it needs a cell with a formula. **With my fancy, efficient array, I can't goal seek anymore!!!!!**

Is there a way to run some version of Goal Seek NOT on excel sheet ranges but on array members, like on **MyArray(107,23)** by testing an input value that is actually on the excel sheet, like **Range("B2")**? What would that code look like?

Answer (score 2):

The first subroutine uses Range while the second uses Array instead. The goal here is 0.

First subroutine :

```
 Sub GoalSeekWithRange()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
       Range("C" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("A" & i)
     Next

 End Sub
```

Second subroutine :

```
Sub GoalSeekWithArray()

Dim arGoal As Variant
Dim arChanging As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    Set arGoal = .Range("C1:C10")
    Set arChanging = .Range("A1:A10")
End With


Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    arGoal(i, 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=arChanging(i, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

To avoid headaches, remember an array of range has **two dimensions**
Probably, you will have to adapt these codes to fit your specific need